# Ransack with kaminari on rails 4.1 error with empty search string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari, ransack, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am using Ransack simple search with kaminari for pagination successfully on rails 4.0.4. I have upgraded rails with this project to 4.1.0, which is the only change, and now if I search without entering any inputs in the search form I get: undefined method `delete_if' for "":String This previously worked with the earlier version of rails!

```
@q = HouseDesign.search(params[:q])
@house_designs = @q.result
@q.sorts = 'price asc' if @q.sorts.empty?
@house_designs = @house_designs.page params[:page]
```

url when it errors note

```
q=?&page=2&q=&utf8=✓  4.1.0
```

url when successful

```
?&page=2&utf8=✓ 4.0.4
```

This is only my second project in rails so I could be missing something but I have spent all day searching to no avail.

Comment: Ransack has really low support (97 jptn issues including with rails 4.1). Try master branch, but it seems like not working with 4.1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was fixed in this commit: https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/commit/71021b558b26d31e4b3b4a03cd595efd35ad25c4

Try running the rails-4.1 branch. It's working for me with Rails 4.1 with this in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'ransack', :github => "activerecord-hackery/ransack", :branch => "rails-4.1"
```

Comment: Solved the issue after using rails-4.1 branch, thanks.